# Regex alternation operator | not working as intended - Python

Tags: python, regex, match

I would like to match **exactly** a target word with a regular expression in the way that the desired word could be anywhere in the sentence/string (even at the end). Also, case insensitivity is a requirement.

Below is an example of how the procedure should work.

```
reg_expr = r'^(.*?(\bfoo\b)[^$]*)$'  

#Case 1
re.match(reg_expr,'foo abc',re.IGNORECASE) 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='foo abc'> # MATCH

#Case 2
re.match(reg_expr,'foos abc',re.IGNORECASE) 

# NO MATCH, WE WANT EXACTLY A foo MATCH

#Case 3
re.match(reg_expr,'abc foo',re.IGNORECASE) 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='abc foo'> # MATCH
```

Furthermore, I have to match tons of sentences and try to match with many target keywords in a single regex. As an example I added the word `bar` in the regex with the alternation operand `|`:

```
reg_expr2 = r'^(.*?(\bfoo|bar\b)[^$]*)$' 

#Case 1
re.match(reg_expr2,'foo abc',re.IGNORECASE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='foo abc'> # MATCH

#Case 2
re.match(reg_expr2,'foos abc',re.IGNORECASE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 8), match='foos abc'> # MATCH

#Case 3
re.match(reg_expr2,'abc foo',re.IGNORECASE)+
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='abc foo'> # MATCH
```

Just by adding the alternation operator `|` we can see that case 2 does not work as intended because the string contains `foos` and not `foo`. 
Could somebody explain why does this occur? What would be the correct regex for my purpose?

Comment: Why do you use `\b`? When using `\b` the first regex will never match `foos`, only `foo`. Also, why the `^(.*?)` part? You are searching for substrings anyway right?

Comment: That is what I want, never to match foos. Also, If I didn't use that part I wouldn't have gotten a match if foo wasn't the first word of the target string.

Comment: Btw can someone explain why I got a downvote so I can improve myself. I think I explained my problem in a good manner and it is a valid question of how the alternation should work. Rgrds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is not with the alternation per-se, but with the fact that your use of `\b` as an anchor is part of the alternation:

```
reg_expr2 = r'^(.*?(\bfoo|bar\b)[^$]*)$'
```

This should be

```
reg_expr2 = r'^(.*?\b(foo|bar)\b[^$]*)$'
```

Comment: I ran across exactly the same regex problem [a few weeks ago](https://bugs.koha-community.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=20458).